# How to update data with TreeStore or TreeEditor component?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I use tree.Panel and TreeStore component. I use JSON file to store my datas but i would like know, how to upgrade my data with a TreeStore ?!

I explain my problem : I have 2 components on my page :

Tree.Panel who display data with TreeStore and Panel to editing data, because i don't find how to editing tree directly ?!

I want to use a Submit button to update data on my tree but i don't understand how to do this?!

If its possible ?!

I don't understand how i can add new node , upgrade node and delete node ?!

Or there exist maybe TreeEditor component ?!

Thanks a lot to helps :)

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. The TreeStore seems to have no method 'add'.

Comment: can you post some of your code so we have a better idea of what you are working with...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think we are yet to see a TreeEditor component. But there are ways to manipulate your existing tree. You should be able to add, update, remove tree nodes using the methods of [NodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface).

You have methods like:

- appendChild
- insertChild
- insertBefore
- removeChild
- replaceChild

etc...

Here is a sample code how you can append a new node to your tree:

```
var node = myTreeStore.getRootNode();

node.appendChild({
    text: 'A New node'
});
```

Similarly you can make use of other methods to manipulate the tree. To insert node into specific location, you will have to use the `insertChild`. For this method, you will have to specify the location as well.

In short, the access point of editing your tree is your TreeStore's `getRootNode()` method.

Comment: Also, if it's helpful to learn more: I wrote a short tutorial showing how to build a TreePanel that uses more than one TreeStore, with both nodes that are static and those that are models, loaded from the server: http://bit.ly/oTePLA

Comment: will it update the visual effect on tree panel after updating the TreeStore by append/inserting a node? i.e. if i have two tree panel with two tree store and if i add one node in tree1 and update the tree2 store then will i see the change in tree2 panel without loading tree2 store?