# How to insert new record ( model ) in TreePanel?

Tags: tree, store, extjs4

I use `TreeStore` & `TreePanel`. I need to insert new node in my Tree , how to this?

I have `TreeStore` component who following config:

```
var monPrestore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    folderSort : true,
    model : 'Task',
    proxy : {
        model : 'Task',
        appendId: true,
        type : 'ajax',
        url : '/intranet-timesheet2-tasks-extjs/getJSON.tcl',
        reader : {
            type : 'json'
        },
        writer : {
            type : 'json'
        },
    }
```

I have defined Task Model (it is what I want to insert) with blank value:

```
Ext.define('Task', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [
        {
            name : 'task',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name : 'material',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name : 'cc',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name : 'start_date',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name : 'short_desc',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name : 'id',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ]
});
```

I want to insert new record when event `itemdlclick` is fired:

I have tested that but it doesn't work:

```
itemdblclick: function(view, model, htmlitem, index, e) {
    var task = {
        task: 't0',
        material: 'm0',
        cc: 'c0',
        start_date: '12',
        short_desc: 'sht',
        id: '120',
        leaf: true
    };

    monPretree.insert(4,task);          
}
```

Thanks a lot :) !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you asked the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5861451/185655)!

There is no insert method for tree panel. You will have to get hold of the tree's root node to modify the tree. In your case, you might have to do the following:

```
var rootNode = monPretree.getRootNode();
rootNode.insertChild(4,task);
```

For other tree manipulation methods, refer the API documentation of [NodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface).

Comment: Oh yes, i don't see my topic ! 

I have understand , your demonstration. but my new problematic if when i want to inserting just after an leaf ? I don't know if is possible ?

I need to adding when i double click on leaf.

With dblclick event i have parameter 'index' , i want to add at index+1

Comment: you must be kidding me!! why do you make a node leaf if you can add a child node? ok, now if you insist you need that way, you will have to remove the existing node, create a new parent and insert your child to it.

Comment: No , i don't kidding you ... ! So sorry
I my case, its success to add leaf when i dlbclick on project ( no leaf) but now i need to add when i click on a leaf in a same level.
The behavior is not same when it is leaf and not leaf?
I see in the doc , there are methods to replace leafs !
So sorry if i don't understand you ...

Comment: then thats the only option for you.. remove the node and create a new one and its child. So, use remove,insertChild and appendChild

Comment: I have solved my problem :
`var papa = node.parentNode;
    
    
    var rechild = papa.insertBefore(
    { task : '',
     material : '',
     cc : '',
     start_date : '',
     short_desc : 'description',
     id : '',
     leaf : true
    },node);
    
    var renode = papa.replaceChild(rechild,node);
    var test = papa.insertBefore(renode,rechild);`