# Loading data into Ext.Data.TreeStore

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I am using ExtJs 4.1. We have one variable which contains data in JSON format. I want to load the value of that json into my Ext.Data.TreeStore. Usually store have loadData() which does the trick. But I do not see any such method for Ext.Data.TreeStore.

**How can I load data into Ext.Data.TreeStore ?**

Below is the definition of my store.

```
Ext.define('my.store.HStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'my.model.myModel',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        timeout: 90000,
        url: '/data/',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Possible duplicates:**

[How to insert new record ( model ) in TreePanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112589/how-to-insert-new-record-model-in-treepanel)

[How to update data with TreeStore or TreeEditor component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861451/how-to-update-data-with-treestore-or-treeeditor-component)

**Answer**

To load data into a TreeStore after the store has loaded, you update the root node as per the documentation here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-method-setRootNode

Also relevant and may help you: [Treepanel with nested data from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040130/treepanel-with-nested-data-from-json)

If you wish to append data to a TreeStore, well that is a bit more complicated... You must first locate the node that you wish to append a child to (e.g., `store.getRootNode().findChildBy()`) and add the child by either `appendChild` or `insertChild` depending on what best suits your use case.

`findChildBy` documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-findChildBy

`appendChild` Documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-appendChild

`insertChild` documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-insertChild

**PS:**
I have answered a few of your questions with no response, acceptance or comments. Please check the questions that you have asked, I'm more than happy to answer them however it is most beneficial to the entire community if you accept answers that you find helpful, or at least leave a comment if you need additional information. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I want to load the data into the store. I have a variable which contains the json string. How can I load that into TreeStore.

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite This is addressed in my answer. Use the `setRootNode` command to load your JSON into the TreeStore. Please follow the documentation to ensure your data is in the proper format.

Comment: so basically setRootNode() == loadData() ? Why couldnt the Extjs developers have just named it the same?