# Can i fetch populate tree store in a buffered fashion in ext js

Tags: extjs

Given a tree store, I want to load data in it through on demand load, rather than loading all data at a time.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

You have to get the root node and insert the child node.

```
var rootNode = monPretree.getRootNode();
rootNode.insertChild(4,task);
```

Found similar question here [How to update data with TreeStore or TreeEditor component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861451/how-to-update-data-with-treestore-or-treeeditor-component)